# min function with key parameter to search through dates - is there a faster way?

Tags: python, performance, date, time

I am using the following code to search through dates, in order to find the nearest previous date in a list of dates :

```
def nearest_previous_date(list_of_dates, pivot_date):
    """ Helper function to find the nearest previous date in a list of dates

    Args:
        list_of_dates (list): list of datetime objects
        pivot_date (datetime): reference date
    
    Returns:
        (datetime): datetime immediately before or equal to reference date, if none satisfy criteria returns
        first date in list
    """
    return min(list_of_dates, key=lambda x: (pivot_date - x).days if x <= pivot_date else float("inf"))
```

I need to call this function quite a lot so I would like it to be as efficient as possible and at the moment it is taking something like 200 microseconds to search through a list of 23 dates and find the relevant one. It does not sound like a lot but this does not scale well. Is there a way to make this function more efficient?

Here is an example

```
pivot_date = datetime(day=21, month=7, year=2019)
list_of_dates
DatetimeIndex(['2015-06-30', '2015-09-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-03-31',
           '2016-06-30', '2016-09-30', '2016-12-30', '2017-03-31',
           '2017-06-30', '2017-09-29', '2017-12-29', '2018-03-30',
           '2018-06-30', '2018-10-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-03-29',
           '2019-07-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-12-31', '2020-03-31',
           '2020-06-30', '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='effectiveDate', freq=None)

%%timeit
min(list_of_dates, key=lambda x: (pivot_date - x).days if x <= pivot_date else float("inf"))

191 µs ± 5.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: It looks like your list is in sorted order; if this is guaranteed, you can use a binary search (using the `bisect` module, perhaps) to find the desired date, without having to examine every single one of them.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks it works indeed, see below answer. Which solution will scale better between yours and fanfly's if I was to search through say a 1000 dates instead of 23?

Comment: Mine should scale as O(log(n)), rather than fanfly's O(n) - but if the date happens to usually be found near the start of the list, theirs might still be faster on average.

Comment: Thanks yes it make sense that it scale better - only problem I have with it is that I don't know how to make it me return pivot_date if pivot_date is in list_of_dates (see function below). How can I manage that with bisect without losing out on performance too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `datetime` objects can be ordered, the nearest date before the reference date is indeed the "maximum" date preceding the reference date:

```py
def nearest_previous_date(list_of_dates, pivot_date):
    return max((date for date in list_of_dates if date <= pivot_date), default=list_of_dates[0])
```

If the list is assumed to be sorted, then one can adopt binary search, which is more scalable:

```py
from bisect import bisect

def nearest_previous_date(list_of_dates, pivot_date):
    return list_of_dates[max(bisect(list_of_dates, pivot_date) - 1, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is indeed much faster (33.2 µs ± 843 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each) but only problem I have with this solution is that it does not handle cases where pivot date is before first date in list and throws empty sequence error. If none satisfy condition date <= pivot_date I want it to run the first date in list

Comment: @MthClv In this case you can set the `default` argument of `max`, e.g., `default=list_of_dates[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @fanfly it works indeed! Which solution will scale better between yours and jasonharper's if I was to search through say a 1000 dates instead of 23?

Comment: @MthClv If there are n dates, linear search takes O(n) time, whereas binary search takes only O(log n) time, so binary search has better scalability. However, binary search can only be adopted if the list is ordered; I'm not sure if it is the case.

Comment: It is the case yes - list will be ordered

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by @jasonharper

```
def nearest_previous_date_NEW(list_of_dates, pivot_date):
    """ Helper function to find the nearest previous date in a list of dates
    Important: assumes list_of_dates is sorted ascending

    Args:
       list_of_dates (list): list of datetime objects
       pivot_date (datetime): reference date
    
    Returns:
        (datetime): datetime immediately before or equal to reference date, if 
        none satisfy criteria returns first date in list
    """
    return list_of_dates[max(0, bisect.bisect_left(list_of_dates, pivot_date)-1)]
```

Much faster indeed:

47.4 µs ± 1.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)